# C++ array causes crash if member of class

Tags: c++, arrays, stack-overflow

I'm currently working with a particular library that was not built with STL containers. In refactoring some functions into classes I encountered a stack overflow based on the following pattern.

```
class Base
{
    float values[1920 * 1080]; // causes overflow
public:
    Base() {}
};

int main()
{
    float values[1920 * 1080]; // does not
    Base t;
}
```

I know you may allocate dynamic memory for `Base::values`, but why does it not cause a stack overflow in `main`, but in `Base`, why does the stack space seem so much smaller for `Base`? Perhaps it's something obvious I'm just missing.

(Above example compiled using Visual Studio 2017, default flags)

Comment: `float values[1920 * 1080];` gets eliminated as "unused variable"? Or stack is big enough to hold 1920 * 1080 floats but not big enough to hold 1920 * 1080 floats more? Just my assumptions)

Comment: Does it cause stack overflow if you only leave only one of these two lines in main()?

Comment: @KjMag Leaving `main()` with just `Base t` always causes a crash given the current array size of `Base::values`, no matter if `float values[...]` is there or not.

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode? Try debug mode.

Comment: And leaving just plain float array in the main() doesn't cause stack overflow, right? Can you check if the behavior is the same in debug and/or with optimizations turned off?

Comment: With optimisation disabled, and in debug mode, the behaviour is the same. The float array in main does not cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1920 * 1080 * sizeof(float) is sufficent to blow the stack. (8 Mb)

Ensure that the compiler does not remove values array by setting elements.

Change Base as follows.

```
class Base {
    float * values;
    Base() {
         values = new float[1920*1080];
    }
    ~Base(){
         delete [] values;
    }
 }
```

Also fix copy and assignment operators.

Comment: Does that imply that `values` in `main()` is directly mapped into memory?

Comment: Either the compiler creates a large stack due to known main usage, or it doesn't use the memory due to as-if rules